# Has it ever been practice to clip to ratlines?

Tags: naval, age-of-sail, ships

I am reading a story (alt history) where it describes climbing on a ship with the sailors:

> pausing to clip their safety harnesses to the ratlines every few feet.

Now, I used to work on a tallship, and train people to go aloft.
One of the things we utterly stressed was never to do this.
Don't even put your hands on ratlines, only feet.
Clips need to go to secured points and safety lined.
Even if someone was doing something dodgy and clipping to something not rated (which of course noone ever did), the ratlines were one of the last possible choices.

As I understand it, historically there were no clipping on at all while climbing. And before that none at all ever.
And in the modern day, there are safety lines with moving ascenders and you don't clip to ratlines.

Was there an in between period, where people would clip to ratline, take a few steps, and clip to the next?

Comment: I've read a fair amount of naval texts from the Age of Sail and I've never seen any mention of this activity. Quite possibly this is an author who learned a few naval terms for flavour and didn't do much research beyond that.

Comment: As far as  I know: no. This technique is a fairly recent development. Almost certainly post WW2.

Comment: Which book is it from, what era, nation, and type of ship?

Comment: @Schwern: not relevant, I am not in interested in the book. The type of the ship in the book is totally fictional. But it got me wondering about the historical precidemt

Comment: @LyndonWhite Practices are not uniform. The era, nation, and type of ship would help to narrow down the investigation. The author would let us check if they're just full of it in general.

Comment: It's literally a fictional ship, it doesn't even sail on the sea. I am not interested in if the author is full of it.  The book merely sparked my curiosity. Reminded me that when I first saw the harnesses used on tallships, I had the same misconception. I don't care when or where it occurred, any historical basis is equally good to answer the question. While answering in the negative is hard it's generally possible.

Comment: Fictional ships aren’t history, close.

Comment: @SamuelRussell, fictional ships can inspire questions about history, keep open.

Comment: Yeah the documentary record of the past of a contemporary fantasy blog.

Comment: @samuel I don't want to know about fictional ships. That's what I have been saying. I want to know about practices on any historical ship. The fictional ship just got me interested.

Comment: The thing is, this stack is about "history" not things in history.  History is a text centred discursive practice.  In relation to your area of interest, you are better suited to asking, "Did sailors in the British Royal Navy of 1805 climb rigging by clipping to ratlines?"  "Did American whalers in 1840 climb rigging by clipping to ratlines?"  Superior would be "How did windjammer crew climb rigging?"